# Django Handling Public API use (anonymouse users making calls to API)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am making a simple website with as Django as backend.
Ideally, you should be able to use it without creating an account and then all of your saved items ('notes') in there would be visible to anyone.

For now I have created a dummy user on Django, and every time an anonymous user makes an API call to add/delete/modify a notes, on Django's side it selects dummy user as a user.

It would work okey (I think) but one of Django's API can take a really long time to run (~1-2 minutes). Meaning that if multiple people are trying to make API calls while being anonymous, at some point the server will freeze until the long API finishes run.

Is there a way such case should be handed on the server side to prevent freezing of server ?

Comment: Can you be more specific on what API takes 1-2 minutes in django?

Comment: Yeah, but I don't think it's important, just the site specific. It's custom API that goes web scraping a website and returns recommendations based on web-scraped results

Comment: Dont think there is something django can specifically do about this. If too many users send too many requests for which you dont have the CPU power, the server will stop responding regardless. I would look at optimising the API call through caching. Consider celery https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32726248/handling-long-requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sorin answered in comments, I would go into Celery way. Basically you can create model that collect the data when the last Celery task was ran - and, for example if it was not running since last 24 hours, and user visits the website, you run task again by async way.

You are not even forced to use AJAX calls for that, because sending task to Celery is fast enough to call it on `get_context_data()` or `dispatch()` methods. You could overload others, but these are the fastest and safest to override.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense and since I am still new to web programming I have not though of it. I will look into it, although the reason I though it has to do something with clients is because if I am trying to freeze the server from two accounts it seems that the response for them laggs independently (one freezes but another can be ok)

Comment: Hey, that is not problem that you're new into web programming, basically this is little more "advanced" question out of there. Returning to the thread, Celery uses async workarounds, and that means it does not freeze server and even uses multithreading. You can also use APScheduler, both have cons and pros, the deployment can also be little problematic but I hope you will find your solution here.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that one of your API endpoints perform task that take really long time which means you already have a task or process that can be block http request-response cycle. What you can do is to run the time-consuming (or long running) task asynchronously using celery or other task queues.